# updating start and end dates of previous rows

Tags: sql, loops, t-sql, stored-procedures

This example is a bit trickier than just updating the previous record based on the start date of a new record. I was hoping you could help.

ID 1000 (there are many ID's and we would need to partition?) has an initial start date.

The ID gets linked to another contract. Hence, the end date of the 1st contract is the start date of the second contract. Note that the second contract may or may not be future dated.

However, the ID may get linked to a different contract before the 2nd contract even starts. So the second contract becomes null and void. The 3rd contract now takes precedence and the end date of the first contract needs to be changed to the start date of the 3rd contract. The second contract is kept showing the start and end date being the same.

Any ideas on how to achieve this using T-SQL?

```
id       contract    Start Date   End Date 
1000        1       2017/08/31   9999/12/31


id       contract    Start Date   End Date 
1000        1       2017/08/31   2017/09/16 
1000        2       2017/09/16   9999/12/31

id       contract    Start Date   End Date  
1000        1       2017/08/31   2017/09/14 
1000        2       2017/09/16   2017/09/16 
1000        3       2017/09/14   9999/12/31
```

Thank you in advance.

Kind regards
D

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: Hi Scsimon ,  It's SQL 2014.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for the sample data, but would fail if there could be more than 1 contract that would be null and void **in a row**.

```
declare @table table (id int, contract int, StartDate date, EndDate date)
insert into @table
values
(1000,1,'20170831',NULL),
(1000,2,'20170916',NULL),
(1000,3,'20170914',NULL)

;with cte as(
select 
    id
    ,contract
    ,StartDate
    ,EndDate
    ,NewEndDate = case when StartDate > lead(StartDate) over (partition by id order by contract) then StartDate else  lead(StartDate) over (partition by id order by contract) end
from @table t),

cte2 as(
select
    id
    ,contract
    ,StartDate
    ,EndDate
    ,NewEndDate = case when NewEndDate = Lead(NewEndDate) over (partition by id order by contract) then Lead(StartDate,2) over (partition by id order by contract) else NewEndDate end 
from
    cte
)


update cte2
set EndDate = NewEndDate

select * from @table
```

**EDIT FOR 99 NULL AND VOID IN A ROW**

```
declare @table table (id int, contract int, StartDate date, EndDate date)
insert into @table
values
(1000,1,'20170831',NULL),
(1000,2,'20170916',NULL),
(1000,2,'20170915',NULL),
(1000,3,'20170914',NULL)

;with cte as(
select 
    id
    ,contract
    ,StartDate
    ,EndDate
    ,NewEndDate =min(StartDate) over (partition by id order by contract ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND 99 FOLLOWING )
from    
    @table),

cte2 as(
select
    id
    ,contract
    ,StartDate
    ,EndDate
    ,NewEndDate = isnull(case when NewEndDate = lag(NewEndDate) over (partition by id order by contract) then StartDate else NewEndDate end,'99991231')

from
    cte)

update cte2
set EndDate = NewEndDate

select * from @table
```

Comment: Thank you :)    There can be more than 1 contract that is null and void.

Comment: So you could even have 2 or 3 rows for example that become null and void. so lead would fail, as you mentioned.

Comment: well, can you provide better sample data? Why not just add a column a a void / active flag? That's pretty common for stuff like this.

Comment: The logic in the example is what to expect but you might have 2017/09/16  appears 3 times as null and void.  I don't have other sample data. I just made this up quickly, as this is the scenario I am faced with. If you added a flag, how would you then do it?  I'm open to suggestions. Thank you so much thus far, Really appreciate.

Comment: i added an edit that accounts for up to 99 null and voids in a row.

Comment: you're a champ!

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: No problem @user3497385

Comment: Any way to change the NULL so that it appears as 9999-12-31?

Comment: sure, i updated the second snippet of code. Just a heads up, this is usually frowned upon... that is, storing fake data as a place holder. It's what NULL is meant for. Just something to keep in mind and be weary of in the future.

Comment: Legend. Thank you. I think they will frown upon the table variable too. lol. but the logic is perfect. Thank you man!  :-)

Comment: well the table variable is just to hold test data. In your situation, you will replace this with your actual table

Comment: cool. I am busy doing that. It's going to be part of a stored proc. :)

Comment: Hi Scsimon. Hope u are well. So while the code works great, I found out that the Dev environment has a compatability level of 100, which does not support the ROW BETWEEN function. Any ideas?